# Can't get finite flow of tweets from ntwitter using socket.io

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, ntwitter

I have my below code that uses socket.io to get tweets from my back-end. I'm using ntwitter and am opening up a stream. I'm trying to get the tweets into a queue so that I can have them float across the screen at different time intervals, but the socket never stops getting tweets so my queue isn't accessible form my front-end in angular. I do successfully pull the tweets, because I console.log them, I just can't have them show up on the front-end.

```
socket.on('tweet', function(data){
  $scope.tweetObject = {
    "user": data.user,
    "text": data.text
  }
  $scope.queue.enqueue(tweetObject);
  $scope.tweet = $scope.queue.dequeue();
  console.log($scope.tweet);
});
```

my html front-end

```
<div ng-controller="mainSpaceController">
  <div class="tweet" ng-repeat="x in tweetObject">
    <p> in the field</p>
      {{x.user}}
      {{x.text}}

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question or are you going to expand one? In any case please don't forget to thank authors for their time if they helped you.

Comment: I did not. what do you mean by expand one?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to add `response.end()` in the end of the response handler on your nodejs backend.

And don't forget to invoke `$scope.$apply()` after updating your scope with new data to force a digest cycle. Your iteration will be l

**Update:** In your example `tweetObject` is not an array it's just a plain object. So you're iterating over its properties, see more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties).

The updated code:

```
<div ng-controller="mainSpaceController">
    <div class="tweet" ng-repeat="(user, text) in tweetObject">
        <p> in the field</p>
        {{user}}
        {{text}}
    </div>
</div>
```